# Emergency Email Server

Tags: email, g-suite

#### Preface

*Skip this if you just want the question, just some background*

We've been using Google Apps for Domains for years with out any (major) issues. But yesterday I removed an alias domain and added it new (secondary) domain. Then I changed my primary email address form richard@old-company.co.uk to richard@newcompany.com.

But, this removed my admin rights, I just keep getting bounced to;

> https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/newcompany.com/UserHub

I can't login using richard@old-company.co.uk at:

> https://www.google.com/a/old-company.co.uk/

It fails and trying to reset the admin password results in a server error. And to boot richard@old-company.co.uk was/is my only admin account.

All this has resulted in my email richard@newcompany.com working but all other *@newcompany.com emails bouncing - *@old-company.co.uk still work however.

#### Question

After scouring Google forums for answers to the above situation it seems this is a semi-regular issue but Google can take 2 weeks to respond!

What I need is an emergency mail server, I just want to point my newcompany.com MX records at this server and it to accept all emails (I can filter later). Are there services that do this, anyone will do (except Google).

Comment: Do you have sufficient bandwidth to host this locally? If so you could always download a feww mail server like hmail and set it up in house.

Comment: Maybe see if you can get something like [backup mx](http://dyn.com/email/dyn-email-backup-mx/) setup?

Answer (score 8):

What about something like MXLogic? (which was sold to mcafee)

It's a SaaS spam filter, but most provide outage protection, where they are storing the email for the length of the outage.

"McAfee intelligently synchronizes and delivers an accurate record of up to 60 rolling days of outage-period message activity"

Comment: and most provide access to that email during the outage through a webmail client of some kind.

Comment: Except Postini, sadly.  But +1 for the spooling/queueing idea.

Answer (score 4):

Might be just as quick to get a VPS from somewhere, install Exim and deliver all the mail to a single local user (after changing your MX to point to that server obviously).

Comment: +1 for a good idea but I haven't got the time to learn Exim, thats why I went for Google in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Why not a [hosted Exchange account at Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/apps/email_hosting/exchange_hosting/)?  10 bucks a mailbox; setup your recipient policy, mailboxes, (remove mailbox size limits), accepted domain, change over your MX.  Done.

Pull everyone's mail down as a PST when you're done; re-import into Google via their migration tools.

Answer (score 1):

We use [www.dnsmadeeasy.com](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com) to provide backup Mail servers for us. Costs about $13/year. We simply add their mail servers to our MX records (just a lower priority than our primary server which is located elsewhere) and it works great. When our primary server comes back online we get the queued email, or if the server died, we'd sort out a new mail server and insert a new MX record.

We use [verygoodemail.com](http://Www.verygoodemail.com) (UK based, excellent customer service) for hosted email on one of our domains. It's very good value (like the suggestion for hosted exchange at rackspace)